# Add an entry on a virtual property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to asp.net & mvc entity framework.
I'm doing a backoffice for managing applications

Here is my App class:

```
 public class AsyApp
{
    [Key]
    public int AsyAppId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Nom")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"com\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "Le Bundle n'est pas de la bonne forme (ex: com.Company.AppName)")]
    public string Bundle { get; set; }

    public virtual Theme Theme { get; set; }
    public virtual AppIdentity AppIdentity { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Scene> Scenes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
}
```

The app has an AppIdentity attached to it:

```
public class AppIdentity
{


    [DisplayName("Ecran d'accueil")]
    public virtual FilePath Splashscreen { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Icon")]
    public virtual FilePath Icon { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Logo Application")]
    public virtual FilePath LogoApp { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Logo Client")]
    public virtual FilePath LogoClient { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("AsyApp")]
    public int AsyAppId { get; set; }

    public virtual AsyApp AsyApp { get; set; }

}
```

And here is my dbcontext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<AsyApp> AsyApps { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Theme> Themes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Scene> Scenes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AppIdentity> AppIdentities { get; set; }

    public DbSet<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view where I edit the AppIdentity of the application.
I would like to update for instance the Splashscreen property.

The behavior that I expect is that when I do

```
appIdentity.Splashscreen = new FilePath();
```

It add an entry on the FilePaths dbset;
Set the AsyAppId of the new filepath entry to the current AsyApp.
But It doesn't work...

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
      public ActionResult Edit(AppIdentity appIdentity)
    {

        var f = new FilePath();
        f.AsyAppId = appIdentity.AsyAppId;
        db.FilePaths.Add(f);
        db.SaveChanges();
        appIdentity.Splashscreen = f;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "AppIdentity", new { asyAppId = appIdentity.AsyAppId });}}
```

Any help ?

Thank you in advance, this will help me a lot.
I just don't fully understand how virtual properties works right know

Comment: Does the first SaveChanges work? I mean, is the entity added to the FilePaths collection? Do you find it in your DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this code after `appIdentity.Splashscreen = f;` :

```
        db.AppIdentities.Attach(appIdentity);
        context.Entry(appIdentity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer. It woks !
I had to remove the first db.SaveChanges() though

Can you tell me what the attach does ?
Thanks !

Comment: When you make a change to the Entity object, those changes are tracked and saved during db.SaveChanges() operation. But for object to be tracked, it needs either to be fetched from database, or to be attached explicitly as in your example. It just says, from now on, track changes on this object, and persist it to database when SaveChanges is called if there are any changes. For object to be attached it must have Id assigned.

Comment: ok thanks ;)

Actually it doesn't work completly. It works the first time when I add a new FilePath and set the Splashscreen property.

But when I wan't to update it (like change the FileName property) it doesn't work...

Comment: It seams that when edit the appIdentity, the Splashscreen property is null...
But it is set in the database correctly..

Comment: The AppIdentity object which you are using is received as a parameter of Edit method, and its navigation properties are null (including Splashscreen). If you want to fetch those navigation properties you must query the database, attach wont help there. Attach is used for updating data, not fetching.

Comment: I don't get it...
how can I fetch the db for a filePath, if Splashscreen is null and Splascreen.FilePathId is null.
I can't find my file ....